# Visual C++ 2008 - Additional Include Directories dialog is empty

Tags: visual-c++-2008

I am having a very weird problem with Visual C++ 2008, on certain projects I cannot properly open the "Additional Include Directories" dialog box anymore. I get the following window instead, which is missing the list itself, and where the "macros" button doesn't work. No matter what the "Additional Include Directories" field contains, even if it is empty, I always get this.

[image: dialog]

Have you already encountered the issue? Any idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Does all projects appear like this?

Comment: Only some projects, rebooting doesn't help, it occurs on other computers as well.